# Matplotlib legend showing lines not polygons

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, choropleth, geopandas

I have a geopandas / matplotlib choropleth plot of a specific type of crime in Cheltenham (criminal damage and arson). I generated the plot (and associated legend) with the following code in a Jupyter notebook:

```
lsoaBounds.plot(column='Criminal damage and arson', cmap='Reds')
plt.legend(lsoaBounds['Criminal damage and arson'])
```

I have three questions:

1. How do I get the legend to show boxes, or swatches, rather than lines, to represent the values across the map?;
2. How do I sort the legend from highest value to lowest? and;
3. How do I split the legend across multiple columns?

   Screenshot of output included below:

[image]

Comment: When there are so many items on the legend box, I would consider using colorbar in stead.

Comment: @swatchai thanks, sounds sensible - how would I go about doing that?